# How to derive parametric equations of a curve from its geometric property?

Tags: geometry

A straight  segment of line of variable length $h$ is attached to the origin $O$ and to the other free end $M$ another straight segment of variable length $a$ is attached . Its endpoint $P$ has two degrees of freedom, moves with a constraint in a plane such that:

$$ h^2 - a^2 =1 $$

So please help me to show  *how to derive* its well known two parameter $ u,h $ where $u$ is brought in as an arbitrary constant in (Mathematica or other such ParametricPlot printable) parametrization result:

$$( x,y) = ( h + \sqrt{h^2-1} \cos u  , \sqrt{h^2-1}\sin u) $$

EDIT 1:

where we have set $v$ rotation/crank motion to zero out of a three parameter relation:

$$ x= ( h + \sqrt{h^2-1} \cos u)\cos v - \sqrt{h^2-1}\sin u \sin v, $$
$$ y=( h + \sqrt{h^2-1} \cos u)\sin v + \sqrt{h^2-1}\sin u \cos v.$$

Comment: If $\overrightarrow{OM}$ makes clockwise angle $v$ with the (positive) $x$-axis, then we can write $M = h ( \cos v, \sin v)$. If $\overrightarrow{MP}$ makes clockwise angle $u$ with $\overrightarrow{OM}$ then it makes angle $u+v$ with the $x$-axis, and we have $$\begin{align}
P &= M + a (\cos(u+v)), \sin(u+v)) \\[4pt]
&= (h\cos v + a\cos(u+v), h \sin v+ a \sin(u+v))
\end{align}$$
Your expressions for $x$ and $y$ arise from the substitution $a = \sqrt{h^2-1}$ and the expansions of $\cos(u+v)$ and $\sin(u+v)$. Is that what you want? (BTW: Don't $h$, $u$, and $v$ make *three* parameters? :)

Comment: Yes, thanks. That is how it comes about,editing to reflect it.

Comment: Incidentally, you can parameterize $h$ and $a$ via $h=\cosh t$ and $a = \sinh t$. This will eliminate the distracting square roots in your formula, and also reinforce the idea that $h$ and $a$ (and the relation $h^2-a^2=1$) represent a single degree of freedom, represented by $t$.

Comment: I did that already, leading to bipolar coordinate $\tau$ surfaces.